# Express js - Promise pending in database connection

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

In my login form I have an option that allow me to select which database I want to connect, so I'm trying to create a function to do that.

In db config file I have a function named `setDB` that go to another function named `makeConnection` sending the dbname as parameter and handle the result of this function.

The problem is that second function doesn't return any result but a `promise pending`.

In this function I have 3 return that means error that will be handle in `setDB` function but this not work.

```
var mssql = require('mssql');

module.exports =
{
  setDB: (req, res) =>
  {
    console.log('Prepare to connect to ' + req);
    var result = makeConnection(req);
    console.log(result);

    if(result == 0)
    {
      res.send('Unknown database!');
    }
    else if(result == 1)
    {
      res.send('Error trying to connect!')
    }
    else if(result == 2)
    {
      res.send('Connection done!')
    }
    //return connection;
  }
}

function makeConnection(dbname)
{
  console.log('Start connection....');

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Database: '+ dbname);
    var configs = {
       Emp1: {
           user: "us",
           password: "pass",
           server: "ip",
           database: "Emp1"
       },
       Emp2: {
           user: "us",
           password: "pass",
           server: "ip",
           database: "Emp2"
       }
     };

     var config = configs[dbname];
     if(config == undefined)
     {
       return 0;
     }

      var connection = new mssql.Connection(config);
      connection.connect(function(err)
      {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
          return 1;
        } else {
          resolve(connection);
          console.log('Database Connected!');
          return 2;
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Console Print:

[image]

What is the better way to do this?
I want to do a single connection and not do a connection in each request... And for example it have to be prepare to be used by 2 user in different databases at same time.

Which is the better way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Just use the pool -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeConnection()` returns a Promise. So naturally when you call:

```
var result = makeConnection(req);
console.log(result);
```

It will result in logging a pending promise. That's what is should do. Your function immediately returns a pending promise that will resolve once the async operations have returned. But you are not waiting for them before trying to log the results. You need to use the promise's `then()` function to get the results when they are ready:

```
makeConnection(req)
.then(result => {
   console.log(result);

    if(result == 0)
    {
      res.send('Unknown database!');
    }
    else if(result == 1)
    {
      res.send('Error trying to connect!')
    }
    else if(result == 2)
    {
     res.send('Connection done!')
    }
}
```